# How to add range for combobox in c#?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a combo box in table layout panel .I want to add the existing serial ports to it.But it doesn't show my ports in the items.It shows nothing.(I have to mention that when the combo box wasn't in table layout panel it worked, but now it doesn't).

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            cBoxComPort.Items.AddRange(ports);
        }
```

Comment: are you using Winforms?

Comment: @MongZhu yes.Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `InitializeComponent();` without it you should get a runtime exception.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
    cBoxComPort.Items.AddRange(ports);
}
```